# Typescript module check if item has been appended to namespace

Tags: typescript, requirejs

I am converting existing code to typescript with module approach, however, there is a bit of code that I am unsure of how to tackle in typescript. Say you have this

```
featureNamespace = {
    feature1: ...,
    feature2: ...,
    feature3: ...
};

function getFeature(feature: string) {
    if (featureNamespace[feature]) {
        return featureNamespace[feature];
    }

    throw `Feature '${feature}' has not been loaded`;
}
```

Previously the features in the `featureNamespace` were in separate files and being loaded via requirejs and the were attached to a global namespace object.

With the modular approach, there is no global namespace object I can use. I cannot have, for example,

```
export module featureNamespace {
    export let feature1 = ...
}
```

in one file and

```
export module featureNamespace {
    export let feature2 = ...
}
```

in another file and then, somehow, import the module `featureNamespace` and use it to check which features have been appended onto the `featureNamespace`? Or can I?

Comment: If you want to load features on-demand in typescript, you still need to have a loader, because typescript does not provide an implementation for module loader. requirejs will do, there is even an example with requirejs in `Optional Module Loading and Other Advanced Loading Scenarios` at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

Answer (score 0):

You can! What I do a lot is put different features in small files, then I have one aggregate file that re-exports them. I think this will work for your use-case too?

file 1:

```
export let feature1 = ...
```

file 2:

```
export let feature2 = ...
```

file 3:

```
export namespace featureNamespace {
    export { feature1 } from "./file1";
    export { feature2 } from "./file2";
}
```

Let me know if you have more questions and I'll extend my answer.

Comment: Are you sure this is possible? I am getting a "export declarations are not permitted in a namespace" error.

Comment: I'm using this exact method in my code. Strange. Maybe you can't export imports in a namespace? I'll get back to you. Which module loader are you using?

Comment: I'm using requirejs